# Ruby facebook graph api appsecret_proof

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I create an appsecret_proof using Ruby for the facebook graph api?

Facebook has an example in [PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests#appsecret_proof). I also saw an example in ruby in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/bentonporter/2891463).

`OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), <app_secret>, <user_access_token>)`

However I'm receiving an `Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument`

It's unclear from the facebook example what `$app_access_token` is, is that the App ID?

How can I create the `appsecret_proof` in ruby?

**Updated code:**

```
secret = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('SHA256', ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID"], app_token)
dct = {
  'access_token' => current_profile.oauth_token,
  'appsecret_proof' => secret,
  'fields' => "context.fields(all_mutual_friends)"
}
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/" + friend.uid + "/"

resp = HTTPClient.get(url, dct)
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens

Comment: @CBroe thanks. I found my app token from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/). is this the correct token? It's still not working using the method above. anything else you can point me to? thanks

Comment: That’s one way to get an app access token, yes. Did you change the parameters in the sample code shown above accordingly? You need to pass the app token and the app secret.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it. I've also updated the code above to reflect the change. anything stand out?

Comment: No, not at a glance. Order of key and data seems ok. Do you get an error message from the API about the app-secret proof, or something else?

Comment: @CBroe about the appsecret_proof `{"message"=>"Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument", "type"=>"GraphMethodException", "code"=>100}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138566/discussion-between-user2954587-and-cbroe).

Comment: Does your code work if you remove the `appsecret_proof` and set it to not-required in your app settings?

Comment: @MarcRohloff yes

Answer (score 1):

This is code that I have that works:

```
  hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.new(FB_SECRET, OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new)
  hmac << access_token
  proof = hmac.hexdigest
  param_hash[:appsecret_proof] = proof
```

Where `FB_SECRET` is the 32 digit (in my case) random string.

In most cases `access_token` is the user's login authentication token (I assume `current_profile.oauth_token` in your case). This token must be associated with your app. If the API call is to be made with your app's credentials and not a user's credentials you can use `"#{FB_APP_ID}|#{FB_SECRET}"` as your access token.

cf https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: hmm that doesn't work either. yeah, the call works fine without the `appsecret_proof` which is why this is so strange / annoying. would you mind posting your full method? any chance you have it for mutual_friends?

Comment: Unfortunately it is a bit spread out including some code on a mobile client. It might be a good idea to set a debugger using HTTPClient.debug_dev=` cf http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.1.5.2/HTTPClient#debug_dev=-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

I've found another way to generate the `appsecret_proof` for **Facebook**:

```
OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), <app_secret>, <user_access_token>)
```

Excerpt taken from this [gist thread](https://gist.github.com/bentonporter/2891463#gistcomment-1425241)