# Ruby properly set Graph API access token

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to properly set the `appsecret_proof` for the facebook graph API. I'm following up on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906955/ruby-facebook-graph-api-appsecret-proof?noredirect=1#comment72916146_42906955) with more information.

I'm currently banging my head against the wall because I can successfully make the below api call without an appsecret_proof token but it fails once I add the parameter with the error `Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument`

```
BASE_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/"

# get app access token 
dct = {
  "client_id" => ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"],
  "client_secret" => ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID"],
  "grant_type" => "client_credentials"
}
url = BASE_URL + "oauth/access_token"
access_token = JSON.parse(HTTPClient.get(url, dct).body)["access_token"]

# use app access token to create appsecret_proof
proof = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('SHA256', ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID"], access_token)
dct = {
  'access_token' => current_profile.oauth_token,
  'appsecret_proof' => proof,
  'fields' => "context.fields(all_mutual_friends)"
}
url = BASE_URL + friend.uid + "/"

resp = HTTPClient.get(url, dct)
```

I'm getting the access token via an API call so I can be confident that that is correct. Since I'm able to get the access token that means the secret key is also correct.

Where could I be going wrong? Am I creating the `SHA256` incorrectly? Documentation for creating the sha256 is [here](https://gist.github.com/bentonporter/2891463)